# Override default settings in NvChad Nvim

Tags: neovim, telescope.nvim

I wish to change the `layout_strategy` for the telescope plugin from the NvChad default value of `horizontal` to `vertical`. This should be possible by setting `layout_strategy = "vertical"` *somewhere...*

According to the [NvChad docs](https://nvchad.com/config/options) I can override the default settings specified in `plugins/configs/telescope.lua` in my own `custom/init.lua`, but I [also found](https://docs.rockylinux.org/books/nvchad/custom/chadrc_lua/) that it could/should be done in the `custom/chadrc.lua`.

## Question

What line(s) do I have to add to what file to change the default `layout_strategy` for the telescope plugin, and only that (keeping other defaults intact)?

I have tried adding to
`custom/chadrc.lua`

```lua
M.telescope = {
  layout_strategy = "vertical"
}
```

Also tried

```lua
M.telescope = {
  defaults = {
      layout_strategy = "vertical",
    },
  }
}
```

and

```lua
local o = vim.telescope.defaults
o.layout_strategy = "vertical"
```

But that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `chadrc.lua` you would override options like so:

```lua
M.plugins = {
    -- ...
    ["nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim"] = {
        override_options = function()
            return {
                defaults = {
                    layout_strategy = "vertical",
                    layout_config = {
                        height = 0.95,
                        prompt_position = "top",
                        vertical = {
                            mirror = true,
                            preview_cutoff = 0,
                        },
                    },
                },
            }
        end,
    },
    -- ...
}
```

I included my additional `layout_config` in case you want to have the preview part in the bottom half. Also `preview_cutoff` was necessary for me or the preview would never show up.

Essentially, the returned table of `override_options` will forcefully extend the default configs provided by NvChad and the result table would be passed into the `setup` function of the plugin.

Defining `override_options` is the way to go for pre-installed plugins of NvChad. If you deal with a new custom plugin, you'd rather need to call the `setup` function of the plugin on your own in the `config` function of the plugin declaration like so:

```lua
M.plugins = {
    -- ...
    ["any-vendor/any-custom-plugin.nvim"] = {
        config = function()
            require('custom-plugin').setup({
                -- ...
            })
        end,
    },
    -- ...
}
```

This is not relevant for `telescope.nvim`, since it is pre-installed, but I wanted to address this for completeness anyways.

Answer (score 4):

As of NvChad version 2.0 `lazy.nvim` is used for plugin management, thus slightly changing the syntax.

```lua
-- custom/plugins.lua
-- ...
  {
    "nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim",
    opts = {
      defaults = {
          layout_strategy = "vertical",
          layout_config = {
              height = 0.95,
              prompt_position = "top",
              vertical = {
                  mirror = true,
                  preview_cutoff = 0,
              },
          },
      },
    },
  },
-- ...
```